# How to find a particular Sublayout assigned to which content item in Sitecore.?

Tags: find, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have one Sublayout called "A" and i have more number of Content items. I just wanted to find out which content item that "A" Sublayout assigned to. How can i do this.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select chosen sublayout in your content tree, and select `Links` option from the `Navigate` tab in ribbon:

[image]

You will see all the items which links to your sublayout.

Be aware, that if you see any `__Standard Values` item in that list, your sublayout may be also used by items which use that template.

Screenshot is from Sitecore 8, but it works the same in Sitecore 7.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Marek Musielak